# How to check if the user entered the first digits zero in the mobile number using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a mobile field and once the user enters the mobile number then it will display the next field.

I don't have an issue with 10 digits but when the user enters mobile no along with 0(zero) then my script not working because the digits are 11.

I tried index of

```js
function activefields() {
  var value = document.getElementById('mobileno').value;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("showme");

   if (value.length == 10 || ((value.indexOf('0')==0) && value.length == 11)) {
    x[0].style.display = "block";
    x[1].style.display = "block";
    x[2].style.display = "block";

  } else {
    x[0].style.display = "none";
    x[1].style.display = "none";
    x[2].style.display = "none";

  }
}
```

```css
.showme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" onblur="activefields()" placeholder="mobileno">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="showme" placeholder="name">
  <input type="email" name="email" class="showme" placeholder="email">
  <input type="text" name="job" class="showme" placeholder="job">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can remove the preceeding zeros from the value.

Also note you can pass the event to the method to retrieve the value. Saves another look up with document.getElementById('mobileno').value;

```js
function activefields(evt) {

  var value = evt.target.value
  value = value.replace(/^0+/,'');
  console.log('value =', value);
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("showme");

   if (value.length == 10 || ((value.indexOf('0')==0) && value.length == 11)) {
    //alert(x);
    x[0].style.display = "block";
    x[1].style.display = "block";
    x[2].style.display = "block";

  } else {
    x[0].style.display = "none";
    x[1].style.display = "none";
    x[2].style.display = "none";

  }
}
```

```css
.showme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" onblur="activefields(event)" placeholder="mobileno">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="showme" placeholder="name">
  <input type="email" name="email" class="showme" placeholder="email">
  <input type="text" name="job" class="showme" placeholder="job">
</form>
```

Comment: Is this condition  correct    if (value.length == 10 || ((value.indexOf('0')==0) && value.length == 11)) {